# How can I draw a line with lineTo in HTML5 that has angles to match the Unit Circle?

Tags: html, math, rotation, html5-canvas

If I have this,

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById("my-canvas");  
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");  

    ctx.fillStyle = '#f00';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(25, 25);
    ctx.lineTo(150, 25);
    ctx.rotate(Math.PI*7/4);  //315 degrees
    ctx.lineTo(150,90);

    ctx.stroke();
```

It does not draw the line (the `ctx.lineTo(150,90);`) at the angle I thought it would which is from the end of the first lineTo at 25,25 to a 150,90 at a 45 degree angle.  If I use -`Math.PI*7/4` I get what looks like a 45 degree angle, but it points the wrong way.  `Math.PI*5/4` goes the wrong way or rotation.

My question asks about the Unit Circle.  I don't really need them all at once, just the ability to know how to draw them if I need them.

Answer (score 1):

The canvas is rotating this way:

[image]

Comment: How do I get 7*pi/4?

Comment: Before ctx.rotate(Math.PI*7/4); insert ctx.translate(150,25);

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example, without the y offset:
[image: Simplified problem]

Given by the code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("my-canvas");  
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");  

ctx.fillStyle = '#f00';
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(25, 0);
ctx.lineTo(250, 0);
ctx.rotate(45*Math.PI/180);  //45 degrees
ctx.lineTo(150,0);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.beginPath();

ctx.moveTo(0,0);
ctx.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
ctx.lineTo(350,0); 
ctx.font = "30px Arial";
ctx.fillText("New x axis",100,50);
ctx.stroke();
```

The red line is the new x axis, and the black line touches it exactly at a distance of 150 from the origin.

Now overlaying the same red line with your coordinates (and rotating by 45 degrees, so that it doesn't go off screen), we get

[image: Using original coords]

The black line ends at a point which is indeed (150,90), however at the new coordinate system. [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Douma37/65z1p38z/1/)

If you want the angle between the two line segments to be exactly what you pass in `rotate(...)`, then keep drawing "horizontal" lines, but translate the origin to the end of each line segment, so you rotate about this point, not the top-left corner, using `ctx.translate(<current point>)`. For example: https://jsfiddle.net/Douma37/65z1p38z/ (this goes off canvas, but has minimal interferance with your code).

Hope that helps!